# Intercept the video.js xhr call and modify the xhr response

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest, video.js

I have got a working way to intercept the xhr call and modifying the video.js xhr response. But there is the problem.

**My workaround to modify the video.js xhr response are**

1. I modify the main xhr prototype and my add my async function to event listener of "**readystatechange**"
2. My Custom async function is fired. This custom function makes multiple promise xhr calls and join the content and replace the video.js xhr response to my custom response.

   ```
   (function (proxied) {
           XMLHttpRequest = function () {

           //cannot use apply directly since we want a 'new' version
           var wrapped = new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(proxied, arguments));

           // Here we can subscribe to the xhr.send to save the xhr events to local variable, remove the events from xhr

           // ---------------- Add custom onreadystatechange event so we will be able to modify the response --------------
           wrapped.addEventListener("readystatechange", async function () {

                   console.log(this.readyState);

                   // When download completed
                   if (this.readyState === 4) {

                       console.log(this.onreadystatechange);

                       var customContent = await GetCustomContent();

                       // Update the value of the response object
                       Object.defineProperty(this, 'response', {
                           value: customContent,
                           writable: false
                       });

                       // Update the value of the response text
                       Object.defineProperty(this, 'responseText', {
                           value: customContent,
                           writable: false
                       });

                       // As we have successfully modify the response now we can add back the events to the xhr and trigger it here.

                   }

                   //this.responseText = "Customized response";

               }, false);

               // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

           return wrapped;
       };
   })(XMLHttpRequest);
   ```

**The Problem I am facing**

As the video.js xhr call have their on function registered to the event "**readystatechange**". As I added my own function as well, my functions get called first. But due to it's asy nature while my function is running, the video.js xhr event function is triggered and so modifying the response have not any effect.

So what I think if it is possible that if we list the xhr request "readystatechange" events, save them to the local variables and then when my asy function promise returns then we add back the events which we stored on the local variable and then trigger it.

This way we will be able to modify the response and then trigger the video.js events.

But I did not know how to store the events on the variable, remove from the xhr and again added back to the xhr (If it is possible). Can you please tell me how I can do that?

I have above workaround in my mind to modify the response, if you have any better way then please let me know.

Thank You!

Comment: May be this can help which is self explanatory. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50352780/override-intercept-xmlhttprequest-response-in-all-browsers/50391809#50391809